# Jcloud Nova unable to find Floating ip pool extension

Tags: java, openstack, openstack-nova, jclouds, openstack-juno

When i list extensions in nova from openstack i get floating ip extension as

> http://docs.openstack.org/compute/ext/floating_ip_pools/api/v1.1

FloatingIPPoolApi in jcloud declares extension as(notice that in Jclouds namespace is missing **"compute"** in the URI

> @Extension(of = "compute", namespace = "http://docs.openstack.org/ext/floating_ip_pools/api/v1.1")

jcloud returns that the floating ip extension is missing, even though its there in the extentions but under a different namespace.

is the **FloatingIPPoolApi** namespace is not correct in jclouds?

I thought by declaring extensions annotation with the "of" attribute, it gets automatically added to the namespace....maybe thats not the case at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a real bug, thanks for reporting it!

https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/pull/813